# g++ error in compiling while using std::string[5] as a type in std::map<>

Tags: c++, g++, using

I am fairly new to c++, I was making a encryptor to imrpove my c++, at first I kept my Cryptographer class in `cryptographer.hpp` and then added function body in `cryptographer.cpp` and then included `cryptographer.hpp` in `main.cpp` it gave me a compiler error, so I just pasted the code in `main.cpp` like this

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Cryptographer{
    public:
        int n_factor;
        std::string text;
        Cryptographer(std::string user_arg, int user_n_factor);
        struct cryptographer
        {
            std::string encrypted_text;
            std::string generated_key="";
        };
        cryptographer crypted_text;
        void generate_key();
        void encrypt();
        void decrypt();
        std::string get_key();
        std::string get_text();
};

using key_map = std::map<char, std::string[5]>;

void Cryptographer::generate_key(){
    for (int _ = 0; _ < 5; _++){
        crypted_text.generated_key += rand() % 26 + 65;
    }
}

void Cryptographer::encrypt(){
    generate_key();
    key_map keyHashMap;
    for (auto key_letter: crypted_text.generated_key){
        int key_letter_int = (int) key_letter;
        std::string key_letter_arr[5];
        int memory_number = key_letter_int;
        
        for (int index=0; index < 5; index++){
            if (memory_number+n_factor > 91){
                memory_number = 65;
            }else{
             key_letter_arr[5] = std::string(1, char (memory_number + n_factor));
             memory_number += n_factor;   
            }
        }
        keyHashMap.emplace(key_letter, key_letter_arr);
    }
    for(int index=0; index<text.size(); index++){
        int key = index %4;
        int key_patter = rand()% 4;
        int checking_index = 0;
        for (auto &elem: keyHashMap){
            if (checking_index == key){
                std::cout << elem.second[1];
            }
        }
    }
    crypted_text.encrypted_text = "test";
}

Cryptographer::Cryptographer(std::string user_arg, int user_n_factor):
    text(user_arg), n_factor(user_n_factor)
{}



int main(){
    Cryptographer crypter("hello guys", 3);
    crypter.encrypt();
    std::cout << crypter.get_text();
    return 0;
}
```

and ran this in my terminal

`g++ main.cpp -o test`
and it popped this large error
https://hastebin.com/cibeyanoro.cpp

I am on ubuntu 20.04, I also tried removing and reinstalling latest version of g++ but the same error pops up.

Comment: `using key_map = std::map<std::string, std::string[5]>;` Are you sure you want an array of five strings here? If so you probably want `std::array<std::string, 5>` rather than the C-style `std::string[5]`.

Comment: There's also stuff that's just definitely wrong. `std::string key_letter_arr[5];` followed by accessing `key_letter_arr[5]` is just incorrect. `key_letter_arr` is an array of 5 `std::string` objects, `key_letter_arr[5]` would be the sixth such object. I would suggest trying to write much less code in between attempts to compile and make sure it works as expected.

Comment: @NathanPierson oh yea the second one was maybe some of my carelessness also do i need to include `array` to do the using thing?

Comment: How can a compile error *not* be related to code?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use `std::array` you need to `#include <array>`.

Comment: @sweenish I am really sorry about that but when I tried to put a small title stackoverflow said I need to change the title

Comment: You also forgot `#include <string>`.

Comment: In that huge error message, pay attention to the `main.cpp:46:54:   required from here` line. It points to line 46 in your `main.cpp`. And the whole message boils down to that you can’t call `keyHashMap.emplace(char&, string[5])`.

Comment: _"stackoverflow said I need to change the title"_, do you understand _why_ stackoverflow said that?  Take a look at [ask].

Comment: @DrewDormann Well before asking the question I didn't what was causing this error was it something like a system file deleted or something related g++, because I couldn't parse that error, I could now surely change the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> g++ error in compiling while using std::string[5] as a type in std::map<>

Arrays cannot be stored as elements of `std::map`. You can store classes though, and arrays can be members of a class. The standard library provides a template for such array wrapper. It's called `std::array`. You can use that as the element of the map instead.

Sidenote: `std::map` isn't the only standard container with such limitation. `std::array` is the only standard container that can itself contain arrays as elements.